# accented characters error

Tags: unicode, accents, font-encodings, french, babel-french

I'm writing with french language.
Document and chapters title are okey but the main text like this:
[image: text]
Here the used packages:

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a TeX error you should ask about the *error* (the typeset output after an error is usually meaningless)

With your preamble you will get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.
```

because you load `inputenc` twice with incompatible options.

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

In fact in your case the second one is the one that you want, so delete the first of these lines.